# cant get my slideshow to work

Tags: javascript, slideshow, setattribute

i am making a simple slideshow that has back and forward buttons.
here is the code

```
<div align="center">
<img src="prev.png" alt="previous" align="absmiddle" width="30" height="30" onClick="prev();"><img src="image 1.png" id="img" alt="slideshow"><img src="next.png" alt="next" align="absmiddle" width="30" height="30" onClick="next();">
</div>
<script>
var slide = 1;
var img = document.getElementById('img');
if (slide == 4) {
    slide = 1;
}
function next() {
    slide += 1;
    img.removeAttribute("src");
    img.setAttribute("src, image " + slide + ".png");
}
function prev() {
    slide -= 1;
    img.removeAttribute("src");
    img.setAttribute("src, image " + slide + ".png");
}
</script>
```

the next and previous buttons work fine but the images (image 1.png, image 2.png and image 3.png) are not coming up as images.
help?

Comment: Like @ozil stated you only need to update the `src` attribute. But the main error is that you are not setting the correct attribute, change your code to: `img.setAttribute("src", "image" + slide + ".png");`. Right now you're trying to set an attribute named `src, imageN.png` which of course doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ozil stated you only need to update the `src` attribute. But the main error is that you are trying to modify an unexisting attribute. Right now you are trying to set an attribute named `src, imageN.png` where `N` is the current image number, which of course does not exist. Since `setAttribute()` requires two arguments, the attribute you would like to change and the new value, you will have to change your code to:

```
img.setAttribute("src", "image" + slide + ".png");
```

***note*** that you do not have to use `removeAttribute()` prior to calling `setAttribute()`.

Answer (score 0):

dont need to remove
`img.removeAttribute("src");`
only update the `src` `attribute`